# Set the product type to "variable" by default in admin new product pages

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, wp-admin

I'm creating a WooCommerce store with variable products only. When creating new products I always need to manually change the Product Data to Variable Product. When you have hundreds of products, this is becoming kind of a pain :)

I've searched around the Internet but wasn't able to find anything...

```
<php?
// Code here
?>
```

I'm looking for a PHP snippet to set Variable Product as default when creating new products, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** - The following code will select "variable" by default on the product type select field, in backend for new product pages:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'product_type_selector_filter_callback' );
function product_type_selector_filter_callback() {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if( $pagenow === 'post-new.php' && $post_type === 'product' ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('select#product-type').val('variable').change();
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hi Loic, nice but I don't want to get rid of all the other ones (if someday something changes), just wanted to have Variable on top or selected by default. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Hi Loic, perfect! I just needed to add inverted commas to 
$pagenow === 'post-new.php'
as it crashed my site otherwise. T'es un boss :)

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, thank You for this example. This only changes default value in select box, but don't change the tab content on the right side. Simple product tab content is active when variable (or another) product type is selected by default. Can You please help with that?